# copy files via ADB from SDCARD to PC

Tags: android, file, memory-management, adb, copy-paste

I have tried reading several solutions, but none of them work for me at the moment.

I want to copy the files present in the sd memory on my computer, but when

I call via adb / sdcard etc., it displays the internal memory of the device and not the SD

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. /sdcard is not the removable micro sd card now adays but external storage.

Comment: @blackapps have a solution for read microSD?

Comment: Use the right path. Find out the right path. Like /storage/3DA4-648E.

Comment: "I have tried reading several solutions" what solutions. Please edit your questions and include all the commands you tried, otherwise we can not know what you have already tried and where you made a mistake.